# Converting Ampersand from Wordpress Rest API in Astro dynamic routes

Tags: wordpress-rest-api, astrojs

I want to build a static website with Astro and WordPress as CMS. I get the categories via WordPress Rest API. One category has an ampersand in its name. **"This & That"**. The API response for the name is **"`This &amp; That`"**

Is there a possibility in Astro to convert the special character before rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set:html`](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) to treat the content as HTML. Make sure you trust the provider of the content when using this.

```html
<p set:html={category.name}/>
```